# Test Maximum Download Speed

Tags: windows-server-2003, vps

I have a Windows based VPS and I want to mirror some files with it. but I want to know what is the maximum download speed that clients can get from the server? In other words I want to see what is the maximum upload speed of my server. I have used speedtest.net but its results are not stable. Is there any other system or site that I can use?

Comment: Have you tried asking your VPS provider?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend just getting yourself an AWS account and deploying EC2 servers in their various regions around the globe. You'll be able to spin up an instance, do a couple download tests, and then terminate the instance. All told, this should cost you no more than a couple USD.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That is probably a good answer I should test that :) But I mean some site, or some service that will check the download speed and report it back to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://www.whatismyip.com/tools/internet-speed-test.asp this site also provide download and upload speed.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Windows port of iPerf called jPerf;

http://code.google.com/p/xjperf/

Or PathTest (my preference)

http://www.testmypath.com/

Both are free.

Sites like speedtest.net are useless because you can not gaurente congention levels. However, using jPerf or Pathtest between your VPS and a test machine doesn't relfect what all clients will get. This is dependent on their connection speed, how many other clients are accessing the VPS at the same time, end to end delay etc etc. The truth is that it fluctuates, but jPerf or Pathtest will give you what you want.

Comment: Good answer but bad I don't have any test machines which have high speed internet connection. All of them have limited download speeds..

Comment: Then how will you ever know that the server is working as it should? Realying on a 3rd party to test it for you, how can you ensure the 3rd party tool/service/platform/provider is working as it/they should?

Comment: Get another VPS from another provider and communicate between the two, otherwise pay for this service from someone, public services are likely to always be over-run